# want to upload a file to one folder and get the file name uploaded

Tags: java, jsp, hadoop, file-upload, hdfs

This is the java code I use to upload a file using servlet & jsp:

```
 public class Upload extends HttpServlet {

   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
   public void init() throws ServletException {

     System.out.println(this.getClass().getName());
   }

   protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
     //boolean MultipartRequest;
     //String PrintWriter;

     response.setContentType("text/html");

     PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
     MultipartRequest multipartRequest = new MultipartRequest(request, "/home/hadoop/Desktop");

     out.println("succcesfully uploaded");
     copyFromLocal("/home/hadoop/Desktop/", "/vamsi/Desktop");

   }
   public void destroy() {
     System.out.println(this.getClass().getName());
   }

 }
```

Jsp code:

```html
<html>

<body>

  <form action="UploadFile" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Selectfile:
    <input type="file" name="filename">
    <br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Upload">
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

how to get the name of the file I have uploaded... I want to copy that file to the HDFS using that filename.

Comment: problem is the whole folder is copying to hdfs...i want cpy only selecte file

Answer (score 0):

Check [FileUpload](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-fileupload/using.html) from Apache, more exactly [FileItem#getName()](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-fileupload/apidocs/org/apache/commons/fileupload/FileItem.html#getName()).

Comment: actually here the whole desktop folder is copying to hdfs..but i want copy only the file which i have uploaded to desktop